# Diferencias entre "Push" y "Commit & push" en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, github, git-push

soy un estudiante de programación, cada vez que doy push en android studio no sube nada al repositorio, pero si le doy a commit & push sube los cambios, quisiera que me explicaran la diferencia entre estos y el uso que debería darle, gracias.

Comment: **Commit** lo utilizas para confirmar los cambios que haz hecho en tu proyecto. **Push** lo utilizar para subir tu proyecto a un **repositorio remoto**. Cuando haces **push** subes todos los **commit** que tengas, si no tienes **commits** pendiente de subir, pues entonces no se sube nada. Para que puedas hacer **push** tienes que tener **commit(s)** hechos, si haces un **push** sin **commit** no pasa nada. Por eso tienes que hacer **commit** antes de hacer **push**, a menos que ya hayas hecho **commit** antes. Este enlace es una buena guía para comenzar con git: https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2.

Comment: Gracias! ahora lo entiendo mejor

Answer (score 1):

Cuando vas a mandar actuaklizaciones a tu proyecto a la rama master por ejemplo; el orden ideal de instrucciones es así:

1. `git add .` Para agregar todos los archivos al stage, es decir que el sistema de Git sepa cuales son los archivos a los cuales debe hacerles seguimiento
2. `git commit -m "mensaje descriptivo por cada commit"` es el paso necesario para indicarle a Git de que se trata el cambio que estas mandando, pues la idea de un sistema de control de versiones es poder ser descriptivo
3. Haciendo `git push` ahoras Git ya sabe que archivos debe darles seguimiento, de que se trata el cambio que hiciste con git commit

> Git push finalmente es para indicarle al sistema que esos archivos con
>   los cambios hechos deben irse a tu rama/carpeta principal